# Get notified in iOS MDM agent after enrollment

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I have an MDM server and I'm able to check in and push profiles to the device. Now I need to send details to MDM server with the help of an agent app.

The challenge I'm facing is to identify the device on the server side as apple has discontinued the following:

1. Retrieval of UDID
2. Retrieval of WiFi MAC address

I explored regarding this and found few solutions on stack overflow as :

1. **Using Push notification** : Need to register for push notification on the iOS application.
2. **Using Managed App Configuration** : Sending a plist from the MDM using the com.apple.configuration.managed

The drawback with Managed App Configuration is that I need to push the app from the MDM. I need to install the app from App Store and still send a token to the device.

I wasn't able to setup the push notifications approach.

Is there a better approach to this problem? I only need an ID on my iOS app. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: I'm not sure, but think that there is was ability to install apps with some configuration through MDM. Path unique id in configuration, that app should use.

Comment: I think its ManagedApp configuration. But with this we have to install the app through the MDM. I have seen many apps in the App Store who are able to achieve this without managed app configuration

Comment: If you need just ID, why not use `identifierForVendor`?

Comment: Unfortunately MDM's dont store the ID returned by identifierForVendor

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit struggling to understand the problem, but what you can do:

- Get some sort of ID in your app.
- Write it to MAF dictionary
- Read the dictionary from MDM after enrollment.

Comment: What is the MAF dictionary?

Comment: Managed application feedback?